# WPF - Custom reusable button displays no text

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

This is the code I'm currently using to animate a simple back button that is reusable, the problem is that I also need another button with the same properties but with the possibility to specify a text depending on the screen that it is going to be used.

What do I have to add in order to display the effect plus the text? (All my attempts to add text just make the button dissapear completly.)

```
<UserControl x:Class="SantaBarbara.Resources.BackButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             >
    <Button Width="116" Height="119" Canvas.Top="57" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent">
        <Button.Style>            
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Style.Resources>
                    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" Color="#990050" Opacity="0.50" />                    
                </Style.Resources>
                <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">

                            <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOverAnimation">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0.9" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" />
                                </Storyboard>
                                <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOutAnimation">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.5" To="0.5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="Border" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                            <Grid>
                                <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" >
                                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"  Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
                                </Border>
                            </Grid>

                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOverAnimation}" />
                                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOutAnimation}" />
                                    </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>        
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: `<local:BackButton><TextBlock>Derp</TextBlock></local:BackButton>`

Comment: simply set content of the button to the text you want.

Comment: Both solutons cause the button to dissapear completly. What is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a small addition. To set the `Button`'s default `Background` in the `Style`.

You have your `Brush` as a resource, need to set it in the Style Setter for Default.

Something like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Style.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush"
                     Opacity="0.50"
                     Color="#990050" />
  </Style.Resources>
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
          Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Background"
          Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" />
  ...
```

You can then extract the `Style`, specify a `x:Key` and apply it to the Buttons you want. Just tried it out and it works fine with the animations